# MySQL writing a query with 2 million records to a new table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache

I have 5 tables, each with 1.8 to 2 million records in, with each table having overlapping columns.

I am trying to populate a new table with only the columns & records I need however in my estimate my query is going to take 1.7 days to complete.

I've extended apache, mysql and php memory usages in the GB range and set any and all timeouts to be in the 10s of days region.

So, my question is what would be the best way to populate this new table?
Once I am done I can drop tables 1,2,3,4 & 5 for the new table.

Here's my query:

```
insert into new_table 
(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9)
select 
t1.col1,t.2col2,t.3col3,.t4col4,t5.col5,t1.col6,t1.col7,t2.col8,t3.col9
from
table1 as t1,
table2 as t2,
table3 as t3,
table4 as t4,
table5 as t5
where
t1.col1 = t2.col1
and
t1.col1 = t3.col1,
and
t1.col1 = t4.col1,
and
t1.col1 = t5.col1
```

Comment: Do you have an index on the `col1` from each table, or is it a primary key?

Comment: Are there any indexes on the table (col1)?

Comment: The data was a complete mess so it has no primary keys or indexes on any of the tables.

Comment: 1. Make your joins explicit, not implicit. 2. If you don't have indexes on the columns being used for the joins, put indexes on those columns. 3. This doesn't sound like it needs PHP or Apache involved at all, and it would be best if it didn't.

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench, php will use the new table created.

Comment: Just because the data *was* a mess doesn't mean it has to stay that way. Indexes are not going to alter or otherwise harm the existing data. Also, 2 million rows isn't all that much and your estimates are likely higher than they would otherwise be because of a lack of indexes. Without indexes mySQL will do horrible things like copy all of the data to disk-based temp tables and use filesort. *With* indexes much of the heavy lifting takes place in memory and goes orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: ok.. So I guess I need to slap an index on the column I am using for matching and use joins instead of what I done above.

Comment: You are currently using joins, they are just implicit joins. Explicit joins are better for readability but implicit joins do work fine. The key is that all tables should have primary keys (ALL of them) or your tables will be unnecessarily slow, to the point of being unusable.

Comment: After checking... Tables 2 to 5 have primary keys but table 1 doesn't. There are no other indexes created. The target table has a primary key and 2 indexes setup. I am now nearly 24 hours in and the query is still running! Go on! Should be done by Sat (started Wed 11pm) lol! Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately this is very simple. You can add `SELECT` query to `CREATE TABLE`.

```
CREATE TABLE newtable SELECT t1.c1,t2.c2,t3.c3,t4.c4,t5.c5 FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.c1 = t3.c1
INNER JOIN t4 ON t1.c1 = t4.c1
INNER JOIN t5 ON t1.c1 = t5.c1
```

And so on, however you are currently creating your current `SELECT` statements. I used explicit joins because I think they are easier to understand, but your query will work as well. You may also want to add a `PRIMARY KEY`, but you can always modify the table to do that afterwards.

```
ALTER TABLE newtable ADD PRIMARY KEY(c1);
```

And that's it! You're done.

Comment: After checking... Tables 2 to 5 have primary keys but table 1 doesn't. There are no other indexes created. The target table has a primary key and 2 indexes setup. I am now nearly 24 hours in and the query is still running! Go on! Should be done by Sat (started Wed 11pm) lol! Fingers crossed! If it doesn't work I will stick a primary key on table1 and alter my query to use joins and see how quick it is on 10,000 records to predict how long it will take. If it works out to be in the days region again I work out some kind of batch processing to only do 10,000 records at a time via php.